# Avoiding re-organizing of factors when using tapply

Tags: r

I'm using tapply(), in RStudio, to summarize and reorganize my data a bit so I can make nicer plots, as per https://www.r-bloggers.com/building-barplots-with-error-bars/ . The code works just fine, see below, except that it reorganizes my factors alphabetically which leads to annoyingly organized plots. As you can see here:
[image: example plot, some info cut]

The factors are in alphabetical order, but I'd prefer to have the control as the last bar in each group. Is there a way to stop this re-organization?

If you're looking to reproduce the issue, the link above provides a reproducible example with the exact same issue. This is the code I'm using. Note though that the image shown above has some stuff cropped out for simplicity.

```
OCCtabbedMeans <- tapply(occdata2$mean, list(occdata2$dist3,
                                      occdata2$Dispersal_window),
                  function(x) c(x = x))
OCCtabbedSE <- tapply(occdata2$se, list(occdata2$dist3,
                                 occdata2$Dispersal_window),
               function(x) c(x = x))

OCCbarCenters <- barplot(height = OCCtabbedMeans,
                  beside = TRUE, las = 1,
                  ylim = c(0, 1),
                  cex.names = 0.75,
                  main = NULL,
                  xaxt="n",
                  ylab = "y",
                  xlab = "x",
                  border = "black", axes = TRUE,
                  legend.text = TRUE,
                  args.legend = list(title = NULL, 
                                     x = "topleft",
                                     cex = .7))
mtext(side=1,cex=0.75,"Low",adj=0.15)
mtext(side=1,cex=0.75,"High",adj=0.89)

segments(OCCbarCenters, OCCtabbedMeans - OCCtabbedSE * 2, OCCbarCenters,
     OCCtabbedMeans + OCCtabbedSE * 2, lwd = 1.5)

arrows(OCCbarCenters, OCCtabbedMeans - OCCtabbedSE * 2, OCCbarCenters,
   OCCtabbedMeans + OCCtabbedSE * 2, lwd = 1.5, angle = 90,
   code = 3, length = 0.05)
```

****EDIT**** This question was marked as a duplicate of a question asking how to reorder a factor in alphabetical order, which is the opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the order of factor levels to whatever you want them to be using the `levels=` argument in a `factor()` call.  For example,

```
# some fake data
x <- factor(sample(letters[1:3],15,replace=T))
y <- rnorm(15)

tapply(y, x, mean)
#          a          b          c 
# -0.8467318  0.1967837  0.2303459 

# changing the order with the levels= argument...
x <- factor(x, levels=c("b","c","a"))

# changes the order in the tapply call
tapply(y, x, mean)
#         b          c          a 
# 0.1967837  0.2303459 -0.8467318
```

You can also rearrange the ordering of the output from the `tapply()` call...

```
xxx <- tapply(y, x, mean)
xxx
#         b          c          a 
# 0.1967837  0.2303459 -0.8467318 

xxx[c(3,2,1)]
#         a          c          b 
# -0.8467318  0.2303459  0.1967837
```

Comment: perfect @MattTyers. I added 
a <- factor(occdata2$dist3, levels=c("Asocial", "Normal", "Social", "Control"))

 and it works perfectly now. Thanks